# Rewriting "/bin/" but going to 404 page instead

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, episerver-6-r2

I am using a third-party URL rewriter, Helicon Isapi Rewrite, in my Episerver site.

One of my rewrite rules contains "aaa/bin/yyy" in the 'from' URL. When I hit the full URL expecting to see the rewritten URL, I see a 404 page. All rewrites without "/bin/" works fine.

This is possibly due to Episerver being configured to send all URL requests with "/bin/" in it to the 404 page - so my rewrite rule never gets processed.

Any ideas on how I can tell Episerver to not do that redirect to 404 page for specific requests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET is configured to do this not EPiServer. See [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/54e9382b-743d-495e-a324-b8b57a5214ee.mspx?mfr=true) article from MS